# How can I convert a Numbers or Excel file to a database for AppleScript querying?

Tags: excel, numbers, applescript

Ultimately, I want to be able to do the following:

1. Maintain a record of entries including: ID #, First Name, Last Name,
   Email Address.
2. Set up a rule in Hazel to search a database for a First or Last Name in a document, and rename the document with the corresponding ID #.

Ideally this would run in the background without opening any files, so it seems that an AppleScript query using "Database Events" would be the best option. I don't have any database creating or editing software, though (unless there's a default option in OS X of which I'm not aware), so I figured it would be best to convert the Excel/Numbers file I would have created anyway to a database and then use that database for the script.

I'm testing the following script to convert a Numbers table to sqlite database, found on [iworkautomation.com](https://iworkautomation.com/numbers/sqlite-make.html):

```
property extractDataWithFormatting : false
property coerceNumberToInteger : true
property documentsFolder : missing value

set documentsFolder to (path to documents folder)
tell application "Numbers"
    activate
    try
        if not (exists document 1) then error number 1000
        tell document 1
            try
                tell active sheet
                    set the selectedTable to ¬
                        (the first table whose class of selection range is range)
                end tell
            on error
                error number 1001
            end try
            display dialog "This script will create an SQLite database with the data contained in the selected table." buttons {"Cancel", "Begin"} default button 2 with icon 1
            tell selectedTable
                set databaseName to the name of it

                tell application "Finder"
                    if not (exists folder "Databases" of documentsFolder) then
                        make new folder at documentsFolder with properties {name:"Databases"}
                    end if

                    set thisName to databaseName
                    set loopCounter to 1
                    repeat
                        if exists document file (thisName & ".dbev") of folder "Databases" of documentsFolder then
                            set thisName to databaseName & "-" & (loopCounter as string)
                            set loopCounter to loopCounter + 1
                        else
                            set databaseName to thisName
                            exit repeat
                        end if
                    end repeat
                end tell

                set rowCount to (the count of rows)
                set headerRowCount to header row count
                set headerColumnCount to header column count

                if headerRowCount is not 1 then error number 1002

                set the fieldNames to the value of cells (headerColumnCount + 1) thru -1 of row 1

                tell application "Database Events"
                    close every database
                    set targetDatabase to ¬
                        make new database with properties {name:databaseName}
                end tell

                repeat with i from (1 + headerRowCount) to rowCount
                    if extractDataWithFormatting is true then
                        set thisRowData to the formatted value of every cell of row i
                    else
                        set thisRowData to the value of every cell of row i
                    end if
                    if coerceNumberToInteger is true then
                        repeat with w from 1 to the count of thisRowData
                            set thisDataItem to item w of thisRowData
                            if the class of thisDataItem is in {real, number} then
                                set item w of thisRowData to (thisDataItem as integer)
                            end if
                        end repeat
                    end if
                    tell application "Database Events"
                        tell targetDatabase
                            set thisRecord to make new record with properties {name:""}
                            tell thisRecord
                                repeat with q from 1 to the count of fieldNames
                                    set thisFieldName to item q of fieldNames
                                    set thisFieldData to item q of thisRowData
                                    make new field with properties ¬
                                        {name:thisFieldName, value:thisFieldData}
                                end repeat
                            end tell
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end repeat
            end tell
        end tell
        tell application "Database Events"
            tell targetDatabase
                save
            end tell
            quit
        end tell
        display dialog "The database has been created." buttons {"Reveal", "Done"} default button 2 with icon 1
        if the button returned of the result is "Reveal" then
            tell application "Finder"
                activate
                open folder "Databases" of documentsFolder
            end tell
        end if
    on error errorMessage number errorNumber
        if errorNumber is 1000 then
            set alertString to "MISSING RESOURCE"
            set errorMessage to "Please create or open a document before running this script."
        else if errorNumber is 1001 then
            set alertString to "SELECTION ERROR"
            set errorMessage to "Please select a table before running this script."
        else if errorNumber is 1002 then
            set alertString to "MISSING DATA"
            set errorMessage to "This script assumes the use of a single row header whose cell values will be used as field names in the created database."
        else
            set alertString to "EXECUTION ERROR"
        end if
        if errorNumber is not -128 then
            display alert alertString message errorMessage buttons {"Cancel"}
        end if
    end try
end tell
```

When I run the code, I get an "EXECUTION ERROR" message of "Can't make \"Databases\" into type integer."

[AppleScript readout of error (no error code).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLRm8.png)

1) Any thoughts on why the error occurs?
2) Any suggestions on what might be a better solution than this?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that Database Events is just a dumb key-value object store, not a relational DB. It happens to use sqlite as its backing store, but you can't perform SQL operations on it, only standard Apple event queries. (The authors of iworkautomation/macosxautomation are not the brightest bulbs.) But if all you're doing is by-name lookups it's probably sufficient. The script itself is pure spaghetti; if you want to try debugging it then start by removing the `try` line at the top and the `on error...end try` lines at the bottom, then run it again so you can see where the error actually occurs.

Comment: FWIW, if you know something like Python or Ruby then you should be able to find libraries for reading xls/xlsx files directly. If your spreadsheet file changes regularly, that may be preferable to having to re-export it manually each time you make a change (which is easy to forget). e.g. I use [openpyxl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl) to read xslx files; the odd irritation aside (what's new?) it does the job and unless your spreadsheet is enormous should be plenty fast enough just to iterate over in Python looking for the row you want.